DotLottie React - Runtime Error: Memory access out of bounds
I'm using @lottiefiles/dotlottie-react in my project to show .lottie files but when I pass loop={true} to DotLottieReact it cause below error :

This error only when I'm using .lottie files occures but when I replace it with .json file the error does not occur but I should use .lottie format only.
How can I fix this error?

React Strict Mode can lead to extra renders or warnings that might not be handled well by certain libraries.
Solution: Try removing <React.StrictMode> in your main entry file to see if it resolves the issue.
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  // Remove <React.StrictMode> for testing purposes
  <App />
);

